# Should i make different texture pack for each image button in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I am using 12 image buttons in my game, should i make a single texture pack for all buttons or make different .pack file and .png for each and every image button?

Comment: You should have a single texture atlas, otherwise it defeats the whole purpose of using an atlas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the least amount of images possible to reduce the amount of images that need loaded into memory.

> "The main reason to use a texture packer is that loading individual
>   images is expensive. Loading 200 small images would take a lot of
>   processing time whereas loading 1 image and using portions of that
>   image would use a considerably smaller amount."

[Quote from gamedevelopment.blog](https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/texture-packer-gui-quick-tutorial/)